# Looking for an inset hinge for a 1" wide door frame

Tags: cabinetry, hinges

I am building a buffet that has doors with glass.  Ideally the frames for the doors will be 1" wide all around.  These doors will be inset and sit flush with the cabinet frame when closed.  I have found inset cabinet door hinges but they all seem to be too large to work with a wood door frame that is only 1" wide.

The picture below shows what I am talking about.  Does anyone make an inset cabinet door hinge that is small enough that it would work with a 1" width door frame?  If not my other options are to either use a different kind of hinge that might be exposed or make the door frame a bit wider.

[image]

Comment: This is the second Q in as many weeks where as a European I feel the need to apologise for Euro-style hinges and how they've seemingly become the only hinge style people tend to think of in this situation :-) Although there are plenty of hinges with a barrel that isn't too intrusive if you want invisible you want invisible; and there are actually a number of alternatives (e.g. barrel or Soss) and additionally they all take up less room inside the cabinet than almost any Euro hinges, which I think can be a major plus.

Comment: Wait, @Graphus, I thought you were British, which, AIUI, makes you decidedly _not_ European! ;)

Comment: @FreeMan, hahahaha. I am most definitely not a Brexiteer! <insert actually mad face> I'm confident that Britain will eventually come to its senses and re-join the EU (there's actually fairly widespread "Oh, um, perhaps this wasn't such a good idea after all.....") only problem (only, ha!) is I doubt I'll live to see it since predictions are the whole process will take more than 20 years.

Comment: Brexit or not, I thought that Brits were very emphatic that "UK <> Europe". Maybe I thought wrong...

Comment: @FreeMan, only wrong-thinking Brits think that way. Sort of like what you'd expect from Trumpublicans. Thinking the UK isn't part of Europe often goes hand in hand with "global warming isn't a thing", "why do I have to wear a mask?" or even as far as "we don't need no steenkin' vaccines". I wouldn't at all be surprised to find a higher preponderance of flat-earthers and moon-landing deniers amongst that lot!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a shopping question more than woodworking.

Comment: I dunno. I think this Q is less abut shopping and more about "what options are there to replace these things I know about but don't want?" If you don't know the name of the thing it's hard to ask about it. @Graphus might even have the start of an answer in his first comment. I'm choosing to "skip" this one and let the community decide.

Answer (score 2):

I found these with Google:

[image]

[Elessa CFF hinge for thin frames](https://www.elesa.com/en/elesab2bstoreoc/catalogo-cat-166-sales/hinges-and-accessories--1/hinge-for-thin-frames--1/Hinges-and-accessories--Hinge-for-thin-frames--CFF-B)
 [Salice Universal Hinges Push](https://www.salice.com/ww/en/products/hinges/push-opening-for-handles-less-doors/universal-hinges-110%C2%B0-opening-standard-application-push-special-materials)
 [Invisible Spring Hinges](https://www.rockler.com/invisible-spring-hinges)

Mounting plate dimensions for 2 and 3 not clear, but maybe under 1"

Comment: You know what? I've idly researched hardware for some cabinetry I'm thinking about and I didn't find at least one of these. So well done.

Comment: @jdv thank you! Since i posted answer found Walmart sell third hinge too! **Much** cheaper :)

Comment: This search was very useful for me also, found many hinges new to me. Not suitable for OP's doors I think but I have bookmarked for later 'pie-cut corner hinge' and [this type](https://cdn.globalso.com/yangli-sh/air-truly-concealed-hinge-051.jpg) made my Häfele, Salice and others.